# Thermodynamic / Thermal Property

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, material-science

What is the definition for
          (i) *Thermodynamic Property*  &
          (ii) *Thermal Property*?

What are the subtle distinctions in the *Thermodynamic Properties* and *Thermal Properties*?

Please mention the Physical/Chemical Properties that can be categorized as either "*Thermodynamic Property*" or "*Thermal Property*".

For example, heat capacity is referred as thermal property in some occurrences and as thermodynamic property in other. Whether the terminology "*Thermodynamic Property*" is used when Atomistic approach to Physical Properties is adopted.

Comment: A thermal property might just mean any thermodynamic property that has to do with temperature. It's not a standard term. Worrying about exact terminology really isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal properties refer only to properties describing aspects of heat exchange whereas thermodynamic properties refer to processes relevant to aspects of thermodynamics. Thermal properties are therefore a sub class of thermodynamic properties. Now heat exchange, as is evident from the above definition refers to a thermal property, and is also a thermodynamic property.